# PHP - mySql Query executing twice

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

I am quite new to php and I am just trying my hands at a script, it is not aptly written however as it is vulnerable to SQL injection. I intend to improve on that however that is only possible as I advance in PHP. I am facing a problem currently when I try to POST variables from Java (Android) and use them to query my database. However the script is executing twice, I find duplicate records in my database. Following is the script:

```
<?php

require 'DbConnect.php';


$Make = $_POST["Make"];
$Model = $_POST["Model"];
$Version= $_POST["Version"];
$FuelType= $_POST["FuelType"];
$Kilo = $_POST["Kilo"];
$Price= $_POST["Price"];
$Reg= $_POST["Reg"];
$Color= $_POST["Color"];
$Mdate= $_POST["Mdate"];
$Desc= $_POST["Desc"];
$Loc= $_POST["Loc"];
$Owners = $_POST["Owners"];
$Negot= $_POST["Negot"]; 
$Trans= $_POST["Trans"];
$AC= $_POST["AC"];
$car_lockk= $_POST["Lockk"];
$Sunroof= $_POST["Sunroof"];
$Window= $_POST["Window"];
$Seat= $_POST["Seats"];
$Stearing= $_POST["Stearing"];
$Music= $_POST["Player"];
$Wheels= $_POST["Wheel"];
$Sound= $_POST["Sound"];
$Drive= $_POST["Drive"]; 
$ID = $_POST["Seller_ID"];

$query2 = "INSERT INTO used_cars (make, model, version, color, \
    manufacturing_date, km_driven, fuel_type, expected_price, \
    negotiable, registration_place, no_of_owners, description, \
    current_location, transmission, ac, sunroof, window, seats, \
    stearing, player, wheels, sound_system, drive, car_lockk, seller_id) \
    VALUES ('$Make', '$Model', '$Version', '$Color', '$Mdate', '$Kilo', \
    '$FuelType', '$Price', '$Negot', '$Reg', '$Owners', '$Desc', '$Loc', \
    '$Trans', '$AC', '$Sunroof', '$Window', '$Seat', '$Stearing', \
    '$Music', '$Wheels', '$Sound', '$Drive', '$car_lockk', '$ID')";

if(mysql_query($query2)){
    echo 'success';
    //echo $Img
}else{
    echo 'Fail';
}

?>
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), and the `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Please switch to using parameterised queries via [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: after how many clicks it's executed twice, you are aware that, for example, if I post my data, led to your page with the query() function, and i.e. refresh the page, it will post the same data once again?

Comment: uncomment the `if` statement, and redirect after successful data insertion. Also use `mySQLi` or `PDO` please.

Comment: You could save a lot of code if you use a foreach loop: `foreach(array("make","whatever") as $col){ if(isset($_POST[$col])){ /*COPY AND ESCAPE*/} else {/*ERROR*/}}`

Comment: @Polynomial it's not just vulnerable, hell I would struggle to write code that was *more* vulnerable.

Comment: Folks please read the question description, whenever I type a question about php people, like hounds pounce about SQL injection. I am learning and its a process. Thanks anyways for your 'Valuable' advice.

Comment: @HereticMonk If I understand you correctly, we're not allowed to give feedback on [the most critical web security issue right now](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) ((SQL) injection), because it's a learning process? In my humble opinion, this is a great learning moment.

Comment: I am following a set of tutorials which start from basics and end at more advanced concepts. Although I am very much interested to learn it in a systematic fashion and I think everyone does go through this, its known as the learning curve. Plus if I am developing code to test on my local machine, I do not understand how it can pose a threat to the global web security.  With all due respect, I had myself specified in my question that my code is vulnerable to SQL injection. I know this from the start and I intend to put all my effort and skill into making this snippet better. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for the code to be executed twice unless you are refreshing the page, or something in your connect script is causing it to happen.

My recommendation is to slow down, your script is only a few lines yet with your original formatting it's barely readable. You have equals signs in different positions, useless white space and erratic spacing which I've attempted to edit out for the SO audience.

Try to do things right the first time. Forego the `mysql` syntax, look up `mysqli` ([documentation & examples](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) and implement your code using the object oriented interface -- it's much simpler.

Your fixed code will look something like:

```
<?php
    // Create DB connection object
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");

    // Get our POST variables
    $make = $_POST["Make"];
    ... put them here ...
    $id = $_POST["Seller_ID"];

    // Create our base query and bind parameters
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO used_cars (make, ..., id) VALUES (?, ..., ?)");
    $query->bind_param('s...i', $make, ..., $id);

    if($query->execute()) { // Will return true on success
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Fail";
    }
?>
```

The first argument to `bind_param` is a list of data types: s = string, i = int etc. You will need to list these correctly and in the right order. Refer to the documentation if you need help. Binding parameters completely eliminates the possibility of an SQL injection attack and is the preferred way to use MySQL when passing user inputed values.

On an unrelated note, typically in PHP we start variable names with a lowercase letter. Uppercase letters are reserved for class names.

Comment: Thanks you mate, I will try to improve the code, however the tutorials I reffered to taught me the other way guess them outdated tutorials. Your advice is very helpful and much appreciated :) I guess the problem then lies in my java code, somehow that code is calling my PHP twice. Your answer is very well explained thanks again for that :)

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of tutorials out there teaching the old way unfortunately, which means a lot of people come here in your situation using deprecated functions. Good luck with your program.

Answer (score -1):

in if condition the query executed well then page will redirect to another one.so we, avoid the second time insertion of data.